# Android In-App Notifications Integration Popup not showing

Tags: android, facebook

I have problem with Android In-App Notifications Integration when integrate into my app. The campaign popup do not showing when receiver message from campaign push. It just show notification like this:

[image]

I did refer this guide of facebook to integrate: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/push-campaigns/android

My gradle:

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
compile 'com.facebook.android:notifications:1.+'
```

Have any suggestion for my problem? What's wrong in my way and how can i fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think guide of facebook is missing intent data in `onNewIntent` method. I resolved it by:

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    if (intent != null) {
        NotificationsManager.presentCardFromNotification(this, intent);
    }
}
```