# Does Facebook SDK 3.23.1 include the FBNotifications library?

Tags: android, facebook, push-notification, android-push-notification, facebook-analytics-push

I am following the Push Campaigns Quickstart at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/push-notifications/quickstart. At the beginning of the document, I found this paragraph:

> Prior to sending in-app notifications you will also need to integrate
>   the FBNotifications library.

Based on the documentation at https://github.com/facebook/FBNotifications, I need to add the following to my gradle dependencies:

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:notifications:1.+'
```

I already have this in my gradle dependencies:

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3.23.1'
```

Does Facebook SDK 3.23.1 (`com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3.23.1`) include the FBNotifications library (`com.facebook.android:notifications:1.+`)? Thank you.

**EDIT:** In the question at [Android In-App Notifications Integration Popup not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45367798/android-in-app-notifications-integration-popup-not-showing), the asker is using both `'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'` and `'com.facebook.android:notifications:1.+'`. That makes me think that Facebook SDK does not include the FBNotifications library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was examining the code at https://github.com/facebook/FBNotifications/blob/master/Android/notifications-example/build.gradle and I found this block of code:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
    compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'
    compile project(':notifications')
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}
```

I see how the code includes both `'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'` and `project(':notifications')`. Conclusion: Facebook SDK does not include FBNotifications.